# how to create tabs using bootstrap v 2.3.2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using HTML, javascript, and bootstrap v 2.3.2 for creating three tabs the problem is the last two tabs contents are merged together and the same content is appearing in both tabs.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnail').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });

  $('#myCarousel-2').carousel({
      interval: 2500
  });        
});
```

```html
<div class="comment-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <li class="active"><a href="#basic" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h4 class="reviews text-capitalize">Basic Information</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#fin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h4 class="reviews text-capitalize">Financial and Credit Data</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tec" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h4 class="reviews text-capitalize">Technical and Engineering Data</h4></a></li>
  </ul>       
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="basic">basic information tab</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="fin">Financial and Credit Data tab</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tec">Technical and Engineering Data
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine no issue found [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/rnaf7y7u/1/)

Comment: Why don't you move to the latest bootstrap? Documentation is here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

Comment: and 2.3.2 bootstrap tabs is here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs